# Why is my variable "unresolved" in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a really stupid question and I'm hoping someone can help me understand AngularJS a little better here whilst I trawl through more documentation... please be aware that I have been working with AngularJS for a week now as I have inherited a project off a colleague, anyway...

The unit tests associated with my project are failing with the following error message `"scope.signupForm is undefined in /Users/.../.../.../app/login/login.js"`

In WebStorm my code is being highlighted (underlined grey) with the following messages "**Unresolved Variable signinForm"** & **"Unresolved Variable signupForm"**, the code where this is being raised is below...

this is part of the controller...

```
function LoginController($scope, userService) {
        $scope.loggedInUser = null;

        $scope.signIn = function (user) {
            console.log("SignIn");
            $scope.loggedInUser = { userName: user.userName };
            $scope.user = undefined;
            $scope.signinForm.$setPristine(); // Error here is "Unresolved Variable signinForm"
        };
        $scope.register = function (user) {
            console.log("Register");
            $scope.loggedInUser = user;
            $scope.user = undefined;
            console.log(user);
            userService.addUser(user);
            $scope.signupForm.$setPristine();// Error here is "Unresolved Variable signupForm"
        };
        $scope.signOut = function () {
            console.log("SignOut");
            $scope.loggedInUser = undefined;
            $scope.signInVisible = false;
        };

... // more code here
```

Now this is my HTML code contained in a View (for want of a better word)

```
<div id="login-signin" class="loginLeftBox">
    <form name="signinForm" novalidate ng-submit="signIn(loginUser)" autocomplete="off">
        <div> ... Form Stuff...</div>
    </form>

    <div ng-show="signinForm.userName.$dirty && signupForm.userName.$invalid">
        ... Validation Stuff...
    </div>

    <div ng-show="signinForm.password.$dirty && signupForm.password.$invalid">
        ... Validation Stuff...
    </div>
</div>

<div id="login-register" class="loginRightBox">
    <form name="signupForm" novalidate ng-submit="register(user)" autocomplete="off">
        ... Form Stuff...           
        </form>
</div>
```

Any explanations would be appreciated...

Comment: If the code works, it's a Webstorm issue, which has almost nothing to do with Angular proper. Please retag the question accordingly.

Comment: Hi there, the Unit Tests are failing so I think it is an AngularJS issue even though both forms can be found wthin the $scope, I used the WebStorm example to add/assist to diagnose the issue

Comment: Don't believe those IDEs. They are not so good at JS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your controller in the same level as the form:

```
<form name="signinForm" ng-controller="SinginFormCtrl" ...>
```

Then the `SinginFormCtrl` will have the `signinForm` in scope, e.g.:

```
function SinginFormCtrl($scope, userService) {
    $scope.signIn = function (user) {
        ...
        $scope.signinForm.$setPristine(); // WILL WORK NOW
    };
    ...
}
```

This probably means that you will have to restructure your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, after writing $scope to the console that both `$scope.signinForm` & `$scope.signupForm` where present and defined! Thus I added the following condition to the controller and now all the Unit Tests seem to work?

```
reset = function(){
    if($scope.signinForm){
        $scope.signinForm.$setPristine();
    }

    if($scope.signinForm){
        $scope.signupForm.$setPristine();
    }
};
```

Not sure if this is a solution or a hack?